# how to host 2 domains in 1 tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat

I have 2 domains which point to my virtual server. The domains are accessible using different context paths like below:

- domain1.com:8080/1stapp
- domain1.com:8080/2ndapp

How should I configure Tomcat so that I can access my domains like below:

- domain1:com:8080
- domain2:com:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "virtual hosting".  Tomcat does support virtual hosting.

Since you already have your domains pointed at your virtual server, you can follow the Tomcat configuration instructions here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html

Basically, you will need to edit your `server.xml` file something like this:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="domain1.com">
    <Host name="domain1.com" appBase="1stapp"/>
    <Host name="domain2.com" appBase="2ndapp"/>
</Engine>
```